# How to convert array json into string?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, api

How do I change an array into a string uning php?

Here's the array

```
{
    "result": "success", 
    "message": [ 
        { 
            "date_insert": "2017-01-28 20:14:51", 
            "date_update": "2017-01-28 20:15:11", 
            "weather": "sunny"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the weather output in string . Thanks

Comment: That's not an array. That's a json object. You need to show us how you get that info. If you get it as json, it probably already is a string. Either way, look into [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 2):

First covert your json into array using `json_decode()` with second argument `true`.Then access each array element.

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "result": "success", 
    "message": [ 
        { 
            "date_insert": "2017-01-28 20:14:51", 
            "date_update": "2017-01-28 20:15:11", 
            "weather": "sunny"
        }
    ]
}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);//Now you have an array
//print_r($array);
echo $array['message'][0]['weather'];//outputs sunny

?>
```

For more see docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: OP's question is: _"convert array json into string"_. This turns a json string into an array. The question is quite unclear, though.

Comment: `I want the weather output in string ` means what?

Comment: I don't think the OP really knows, to be honest.

Comment: Hope he will edit question for more?